# Will Bitcoin Cash (BCC) be mined like BTC?

Tags: bitcoin-cash

Will the new bitcoin-cash be available for mining and if yes, is it mined on new fork that will be submitted or on the previous code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will the new bitcoin-cash be available for mining and if yes, is it
>   mined on new fork that will be submitted or on the previous code?

Yes, it will be available for mining, and you mine it the same way you mine **BTC**, all you need to do is direct your hash power to the pool which will be mining **BCC** after the split.

**[ViaBTC](https://twitter.com/ViaBTC/status/888958580774154242)** provide such a pool for BCC mining and it is available now, https://pool.viabtc.com/pool/bcc/home/